# Сделать так чтобы событие mouseout игнорировалось

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть примерная разметка:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item4</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item5</a></li>
</ul>
```

На элементе ul навешаны обработчики событий mouseover и mouseout. Проблема в том, что событие mouseout происходит не только когда я увожу курсор с самого элемента ul, но и когда навожу на дочерний элемент будь то li или a. Мне нужно чтобы mouseout элемента ul срабатывал только когда я увожу курсор с самого ul, а при переходе на дочерний элемент событие mouseout игнорировалось бы.

Надеюсь что я понятно изложил суть. Подскажите пожалуйста как решить эту задачу. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

примерно так:

```
$('ul').on('mouseover', function(e){
  if(e.target.tagName == 'UL') {
    // code
  }
})
```